# Hai. I managed to retrieve current date and time. But how to add the data in my database? Im using mysql,php file,filezilla

Tags: android, mysql, datetime

I have records like Location's name, Lat, Long, and Datetime, I know how to add others field into my database using string name = inputname.getText().toString();  but how about datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Make a datetime column, select now() or whatever datetime you want and insert, simple. Just has to be in the mysql datetime format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'. You can also use unix time.

To make a variable in android studio:

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

Comment: My bad, my question not clear enough. What I mean is, I dont know how to write the code in my android studio activity. To add the datetime data into my mysql database.

Comment: Oh, well I'm not familiar with android but however you are doing your sql queries, you just need to insert Now() as the value for current datetime or you can use this if you need a variable: String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());